# Undefined symbols:"basic_file" on my Mac OS using gcc

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, undefined-reference

I am trying to compile a third-party tool. The command line looks like

```
gcc <many .o files and .a files>  -g -lgmp -lgmpxx -lstdc++  -o bintool
```

which gives me this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

std::__basic_file<char>::is_open() const
```

For info, I find the `__basic_file` above is specified in

```
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/basic_file.h
```

But I do not know where it is actually implemented, and how to correctly link with it. Where should I get started for fixing this? I am on Mac OS. My 'gcc --version' gives:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Any idea on how to fix the "undefined symbol" error? Thanks.

Comment: Try compiling with g++ and getting rid of `-lstdc++`.

Comment: You may want to try `g++ <many .o files and .a files> -g -o bintool -lgmp -lgmpxx` with the libs listed _after_ the `.o` file.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Which libs do you mean? Do you means those of gmp?

Comment: When working with C++, you should really make it a habit to use the C++ frontend programs, i.e. `g++` or `clang++`. When compiling to object files it really doesn't matter, but it does when linking.

Comment: Yes... putting the `-l<lib>` options last is usually a good idea "by default" unless the app requires special linking.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg But the project I am compiling is a C project (It is written with C99). BTW, Is that possible that a C project compiles with libc++?

Comment: If it's regular C, you shouldn't be needing `-lgmpxx` (which in its turn requires stdc++)

Comment: Well *sonething* isn't plain C, `std::__basic_file<char>::is_open() const` is not possible in C, but it is in C++ (it's probably some internal C++ standard library class).